# How to edit detailed image metadata (exif)?

Tags: image-processing, photo-management, metadata, photo

How can I edit detailed image metadata (exif) fields?  In Windows 7 this is just a right click on the file in the folder.

I've searched and not found a way to edit detailed metadata (exif) fields in Ubuntu 14.04.  I'm not interested in running something from the command line.

- With Shotwell Photo Manager I can only edit Title, Comment, Date and Time.
- With Shotwell Photo Viewer it is only possible to adjust Date and Time.
- With Gimp it is possible to edit Title, Author, Description, Keywords.
- I tried Phatch but it wasn't intuitive and didn't appear to have an option to edit metadata, only add or remove metadata.

What I can't figure out how to do is edit Location.

What I really want to be able to do is right click on the image file in the folder browser and directly edit the metadata like in Windows.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 16):

Try [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

> ExifTool is a platform-independent Perl library plus a command-line
>   application for reading, writing and editing meta information in a
>   wide variety of files. ExifTool supports many different metadata
>   formats including EXIF, GPS, IPTC, XMP, JFIF, GeoTIFF, ICC Profile,
>   Photoshop IRB, FlashPix, AFCP and ID3, as well as the maker notes of
>   many digital cameras.<sup>[ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install exiftool
```

Comment: In the question, it was stated, "I'm not interested in running something from the command line." `exiftool` is good for the command line or if you're scripting a solution for a large number of files, but it's not a good solution if you want to make a small number of changes to image files.

Answer (score 4):

You can use DigiKam to edit exif metadata
([how-to](http://scribblesandsnaps.com/2011/02/22/work-with-photo-metadata-in-digikam/)) and apply one edit to [multiple pictures](http://scribblesandsnaps.com/2013/08/07/apply-exif-metadata-to-multiple-photos-in-digikam/)

Comment: DigiKam works super well, but a more detailed explanation would be appreciated over a link.

Comment: The link for editing metadata is outdated and doing this from the user interface isn't apparent since they seem to have their own tag system.

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date link: https://userbase.kde.org/Digikam/Metadata

Answer (score 4):

From the project's website:
pyExifToolGui is a graphical frontend for the excellent open source command line tool ExifTool by Phil Harvey. pyExifToolGui is a python pySide QT4 script program that reads and writes all kind of metadata tags from/to image files. A strong point of this software is the ability to write the data, copied or not from a source image (reference image), to multiple images at once.

https://hvdwolf.github.io/pyExifToolGUI/

Comment: I tried modifying the "Date and Time" data of an image using "pyExifToolGUI-0.5", which was released on Dec 23, 2013, and "exiftool" 10.10 (from the repository), which was released on Jan 22, 2016, and the data was changed.

Comment: The only problem with GUIs for command line tools is that if the command line tool interface changes, the GUI tool may stop working.

Answer (score 3):

GIMP 2.9.4 and later has a built-in metadata editor. It is accessed by selecting *Image* -> *Metadata* -> *Edit Metadata*. The GIMP Metadata Editor can edit a wide variety of image metadata fields including GPS metadata. To write metadata click the *Write Metadata* button in the lower right corner of the Metadata Editor window.

[image]
<sup>**GIMP 2.10**</sup>

GIMP 2.10 can be installed as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu or as an apt package in Ubuntu 18.10 and later.

Image::ExifTool (*libimage-exiftool-perl*) is a library and program (`exiftool`) to read and write metadata information in multimedia files. To install libimage-exiftool-perl in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

To show an image's metadata run this command:

```
exiftool /path/to/file
```

Comment: You can not edit e.g. date in Gimp.

Comment: can't edit the Orientation on Gimp as well

Comment: @fabriciofreitag GIMP behaves differently on different platforms. On my iMac GIMP runs like crap, but it runs perfectly on my Ubuntu workstation. I have never had any problems with editing image metadata fields using GIMP in Ubuntu, however there might be some image metadata fields which GIMP can't edit that I haven't tried to edit yet.

Comment: Mine(2.10.18) doesn't even show "Orientation"

Answer (score 1):

Successor of pyExifToolGui is [jExifToolGUI](https://hvdwolf.github.io/jExifToolGUI/).

The following is about version 1.5.2:

It is rather slow loading, if you choose to load a whole directory with many images, but you can choose to load only desired images, if you know their filename.

The UI barely fits in 1280x1024 resolution display:

[image: Screenshot from 1280x1024 resolution display]

Answer (score 0):

With Nautilus and Nemo, you have a tab with image properties where you can find the metadata.
If you're using Dolphin like me (with Kubuntu for example), wherethere is not  a such information, you can install Nemo and use it instead of Dolphin for this purpose.
I use Nemo for this kind of operations and I am still using Dolphin for the other ordinary ones.

To install Nemo, open a terminal and enter "nemo". If it is not install the system will tell you how to proceed.

Comment: In Nemo only a limited set of metadata is shown. For example GPS metadata aren't present and above all you cannot Edit anything ... So, this isn't answering the basic request.

Answer (score 0):

Another graphical tool - at least for editing the date/time - is the Shotwell Viewer.

In Nautilus right-click the image, choose `Open with other application`.
A list of installed applications pops up.
From that list, choose the `Shotwell Viewer`.
Shotwell Viewer shows the image.
From the menu choose `Photo/Adjust date and time...`
Set the date and time you intend to have and click `Ok`.
Finally from the menu select `File/Save`.